# multi coloured backlit keyboard - any apps to control this in Linux/

Tags: keyboard

I saw one over at Git Hub for MSI keyboards, but not sure if it would work for HP ones...I can turn the backlighting on an off ok using the Fn key, but the factory (W10 based setup) has an app that allows one to set a static colour.

So question is does anyone know of anything for ubuntu that could do the same?

Comment: I know providing link is a bad idea, because I should use copy paste method and provide copyright, however I do not have much time for this and usually look for the solution in Google what usually takes less than 30 seconds for me and the idea which I use is to provide a solution for the particular user. If someone have time, please make a tutorial, I am to busy to do this here.  https://configurelaptop.eu/clevo-keyboard-backlight-control-for-linux/

Comment: Thanks. I did come across that one I think in my Google search, but as it says for Clevo and doesn't mention being ok for other brands I dismissed it. Are you saying it might actually work for any laptop with backlighting?

Comment: You can try. The problem is that I am not sure because I never tested it. I do not play games much. If this app will not work, you can remove it.